# What's wrong in Method $2$ here?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, definite-integrals, contest-math

> Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{2}{(n+2)(n+4)}+\cdots+\frac{n}{6n^2}\big)$

**Method $1$:**

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\big(\frac r{(n+r)(n+2r)}\big)$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\big(\frac1{(n+r)}-\frac1{(n+2r)}\big)$

$=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x}-\frac1{1+2x}dx$

$=[\ln(1+x)-\frac12\ln(1+2x)]_0^1$

$=\ln\frac2{\sqrt3}$

**Method 2:**

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{2}{(n+2)(n+4)}+\cdots+\frac{n}{(n+n)(n+2n)}\big)$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\frac{1}{(n+1)}-\frac1{(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+2)}-\frac1{(n+4)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac 1{3n}\big)$

After cancelling, only first and last term is left.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{3n}=0$

Comment: I edited this to correct the minor error that the two answers noticed, so that it won't distract future readers from the main issue.  (This also changed the wrong answer to a different wrong answer.)

Comment: @TobyBartels thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After cancelling, only first and last term is left.

No. There is a $\ +\frac1{(n+3)}\ $ term, but not a $\ -\frac1{(n+3)}\ $ term. And for odd $k,$ there are no $\ -\frac1{(n+k)}\ $ terms, so the $\ +\frac1{(n+k)}\ $ terms do not cancel with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{n}{(n+n)(n+2n)}=\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{3n}\neq \frac{n}{2n}-\frac{n}{3n}$.  But here is not the key.

You only need to expand more term in the formula
\begin{align}
 &\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r}{(n+r)(n+2r)}\\
=&\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+r)}-\frac{1}{(n+2r)}\\
=&\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+3}-\frac{1}{n+6}\right)+\cdots
\end{align}
Note that $-\frac{1}{n+4}+\frac{1}{n+3}\neq0$.
You can not cancell!